# 'Constructive proof' of $L \otimes_K L$ reduced iff $I/I^2=0$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $L/K$ a finite field extension. We can endow the tensor product
$L \otimes_K L$ with structure of $L$-algebra via
$L \to L \otimes_K L,\ l \mapsto l \otimes 1_L$. Therfore
$L \otimes_K L$ carries also structure of a $L$-module via $L$-multiplication
in first factor $l \cdot (a \otimes b) :=
la \otimes b$.

Let $d: L \otimes_K L \to L, a \otimes b \mapsto ab$ be the canonical
diagonal map and denote it's kernel by $I:= \operatorname{ker}(d)$.
I have once already asked in [Tensor product $L \otimes_K L$ has no nilpotent elements iff $I/I^2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225005/tensor-product-l-otimes-k-l-has-no-nilpotent-elements-iff-i-i2-0) about the proof of the statement that

> $L \otimes_K L$ [reduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring)
> (has no nilpotent elements) is equivalent to
> $I= I^2$, ie $I/I^2=0$

I obtained there a completely satisfying answer but nevertheless
I'm still badly curious if it is also possible to give a 'constructive' proof in
the sense that if $L \otimes_K L$ is not reduced, so it contains
a nilpotent non zero $a  \in L \otimes_K L$, then this $a$ helps me to to
construct an explicit element $i(a) \in I \backslash I^2$ and vice
versa a $b \in I \backslash I^2$ helps to construct
a nilpotent $a(b) \in \sqrt{(0)} \subset L \otimes_K L$.

Question: Are such direct constructions here feasible?

Note: we can use the fact that $I/I^2$ is generated as $L$-module
by $a \otimes 1_L -1_L \otimes a, a \in L$.

Comment: Examining the other proof, it seems the only "non constructive" part of the proof is the chinese remainder lemma and Thm 8.7 in Atiyah-Macdonald. Do you know a "constructive proof" of these results? If you find such proofs you may use the existing proof. You find some information here:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65332/matrix-decomposition-the-other-way/65338#65338

Comment: It seems the main theme in the proof of AM.Thm 8.7 is the chinese remainder lemma and this lemma has a constructive proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I obtained there a completely satisfying answer but nevertheless I'm still badly curious if it is also possible to give a 'constructive' proof."

**Answer:** It seems the main theme in the proof of the assertaion is the chinese remainder lemma and this lemma has a (it has several I believe) constructive proof.

[Tensor product $L \otimes_K L$ has no nilpotent elements iff $I/I^2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225005/tensor-product-l-otimes-k-l-has-no-nilpotent-elements-iff-i-i2-0)

Comment: I not see how you can use the proof you gave in the linked 
question + Thm 8.7 in Atiyah-Macdonald extract following two 
explicite constructions: (I) assume $L \otimes_K L$ is not 
reduced, then $\sqrt{(0)} \neq 0$. How we can explicitely use
non-zero elements from $\sqrt{(0)} \neq 0$ to construct 
an element $a \in I \backslash I^2$ and (II) if we have $I \neq I^2$, 
how we can use elements from $I \backslash I^2$ to construct 
explicitely a non-zero nilpotent element $n \in \sqrt{(0)} \neq 0$?

Comment: @Isakthe XI - I agree that it is not immediate, but the chinese remainder lemma and its constructive proof may be the first a place to look.

Comment: Chinese remainder lemma solves my problem at least in case
$L= K(a) =K[X]/f$ ($f$ minimal polynomial of $a \in L$):
Then we have in $L[X]$ decomposition in prime factors
$f= (X-a)^{n_a} \cdot \prod f_i^{n_i}$ and therefore
$L \otimes_K L= L[X]/(X-a)^{n_a} \times \prod_i
L[X]/(f_i)^{n_i}$. 



Then the diagonal map $d_L: L \otimes L \to L$ is given by
projection $L[X]/(X-a)^{n_a} \times \prod_i
L[X]/(f_i)^{n_i} \to L[X]/(X-a)=L, X \mapsto a $.
Then $I = ker(d_L)= (X-a) \times \prod_i
L[X]/(f_i)^{n_i}$.

Comment: Now if $\sqrt{(0)} \neq 0$, then $f$ is not separable and
there exist a seprable $g \in K[X]$ with 
$f= g(X^{p_m})$ for $p= char(K), m > 0$, a known fact from algebra. Since $f(a)=g(a^{p_m})=0$ 
we conclude $n_a= p^m \ge 2$. 
Choose $x_a \in (X-a) \backslash (X-a)^2$. Then
$(x_a, 0, 0, ..., 0) \in I \backslash I^2$.

Conversely if $I \neq I^2$ then $n_a \neq 1$ since 
otherwise $I = 0 \times \prod_i
L[X]/(f_i)^{n_i}$ would imply $I=I^2$. Therefore we can take a $x_a \in (X-a) \backslash (X-a)^2$. Then
$0 \neq (x_a, 0, 0, ..., 0) \in \sqrt{(0)} $.

Comment: What about general $L$? I not see a direct way to reduce the 
discussion to case above with $L= =K[X]/f$. Say 
we have for arbitrary $a \in L \backslash K$ an inclusion of fields 
$K \subset K(a) = K[X]/f \subset L$ which induces inclusion 
$K(a) \otimes_K K(a) \subset L \otimes L$. 
Denote by $d_L: L \otimes L \to L$ 
and $I_L= ker(d_L)$ and the restricted diagonal map
$d_{K(a)}: K(a) \otimes_K K(a) \to K(a)$ and 
$I_{K(a)}=ker(d_{K(a)})$.

Comment: Also let $\sqrt{(0)}_L \subset L \otimes L$ the nilpotent ideal
of $L \otimes L$ and $\sqrt{(0)}_{K(a)} :=  \sqrt{(0)}_L \cap K(a) \otimes_K K(a) 
\subset K(a) \otimes_K K(a)$. 
Now if we want to be able to reduce the problem for general $L$ to the case 
$K(a)$ then we have to make sure that following two points are true:
if $\sqrt{(0)}_L \neq 0$, then $\sqrt{(0)}_{K(a)} \neq 0$ and 
if $I_L \neq I_L^2$, then $I_{K(a)} \neq I_{K(a)}^2$. Do you see why these
two points are true?

Comment: @IsaktheXI - Why in the above comment can you assume that $n_a\geq 1$?

Comment: @Isakthe XI - if you look in Atiyah-Macdonald and the proof of Thm 8.7 you will find that the essential part of this proof is the CRL which "is constructive".

Comment: For 'Why $n_a$ can be assumed $n_a\geq 1$?'
Above I was only dealing with case $L=K(a) =
K[X]/f$ ($f \in K[X]$ minimal polynomial of $a$). Therefore 
$f$ splits in $L[X]$ ! in prime factors 
$f= (X-a)^{n_a} \cdot \prod f_i^{n_i}$ and since $f(a)=0$ 
by construction in $L[X]$ we have $(X-a) | f$ and 
that's why $n_a\geq 1$.

Comment: back to general case. The Thm 8.7 from AM states that
$A:= L \otimes_K L$, which is Artin ring since
$A$ is a finite $L$-module, decomposes as
$A= \prod_{j=1}^n A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}$ where 
$\mathfrak{m}_j$ are maximal ideals in $A$. Then $A$ is 
reduced iff $k_j=1$ for all $j$, so in non reduced 
case it's easy to construct the nilpotent elements. 

I think here is partial a solution for one direction: Every ideal $K$ in 
a product of rings $R_1 \times R_2$ has structure
$K= K_1 \times K_2$ with $K_i$ ideal of $R_i$ (note $K_i$ 
can be R_i$).

Comment: For $d_L: A = L \otimes L \to L$ the ideal $I=ker(d_L)$ is
maximal in $A$, and therefore if we write
$I= \prod_j I_j \subset \prod_j A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}$
there exist a unique $s$ with $I_{s} = \mathfrak{m}_{s}
\subset A/(\mathfrak{m}_{s})^{k_s}$ and 
$I_j= A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}$ for other $j \neq s$.
WLOG, $s=1$. Then $I = \mathfrak{m}_1 \times 
\prod_{j=2}^n A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}$. Then
$I=I^2$ iff $k_1=1$. If $k_1 >1$ then in local Artin ring
$A/(\mathfrak{m}_{1})^{k_1}$ we have 
$\mathfrak{m}_{1} \neq \mathfrak{m}_{1}^2$ and

Comment: we can easily construct a $r =
(r_1, 0,....,0) \in I \backslash I^2$ for 
$r_1 \in \mathfrak{m}_{1} \backslash \mathfrak{m}_{1}^2$.

Comment: The converse is not clear. Assume
$A$ is not reduced, but $k_1=1$ where
$I = \mathfrak{m}_{1} \times \prod_{j=2}^n A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}$.
That is there exist a $k_j >1$ with $j \neq 1$. 
But then $I=I^2$ since $\mathfrak{m}_{1}= (0)$ in
$A/(\mathfrak{m}_1)$, that's strange. The problem is to show that
if $A$ is not reduced, the kernel $I$ has
the structure $\prod_{j=1}^{s-1} A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}
\times \mathfrak{m}_s \times \prod_{j=s+1}^{n} A/(\mathfrak{m}_j)^{k_j}$
with $k_s >1$. I don't know now to prove it.

Comment: @IsaktheXI - If you are given a direct sum $A \cong A_1\oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$ it follows there is a 1-1 correspondence between prime ideals in $A$ and prime ideals in $A_i$ for $i=1,..,d$: Any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ is on the form $\mathfrak{p}=A_1\oplus \cdots \oplus A_{i-1} \oplus \mathfrak{p}_i \oplus A_{i+1} \oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$ with $\mathfrak{p}_i \subseteq A_i$ a prime ideal.

Comment: The disjoint union of a finite number of affine schemes is affine:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254117/proving-that-the-disjoint-union-of-two-affine-schemes-is-isomorphic-to-an-affine/4255251#4255251

Comment: I think that what you wanted to say is that such decomposition of prime
ideals hold for direct *products* of rings; there exist no
*direct sum* of rings due to category theoretical reasons
(see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_rings ,
or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209200/why-isnt-there-necessarily-a-direct-sum-of-rings)


Note that in previous comments I already used implicitely this fact 
for maximal ideals.

Comment: The relation of your last link and this problem I not understand.

Comment: @IsaktheXI - when you are considering a finite set of rings $A_1,..,A_d$, it follows the direct product equals the direct sum: $\oplus_i A_i = \prod_i A_i$.

Comment: I disagree. What is the $1$ in $\oplus_i A_i$? Note that we talk about the category of rings and not modules! I agree with you that if $R$ ring, and $M_1,..., M_n$ are $R$-modules then $\oplus_i M_i = \prod_i M_i$ as modules, but in case of rings I don't think that it's true. Have you already checked the discussion in the linked mse thread?

Comment: @IsaktheXI - in this context you do not need to worry too much about category theoretical properties of direct  sum/direct product. Your ring $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra with $k$ a field, and you need a constructive proof that $A \cong A_1\oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$ is a direct sum (or equivalently a direct product) of Artinian local rings $A_i$. I believe this should follow from the constructive "chinese remainder lemma", but as I say above: It is not immediate.  The multiplicative unit $1$ is $1:=(1,1,...,1) \in A$ and the product is componentwise.

Comment: Again: When I write $A\cong A_1\oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$ i mean that $A$ is the set of $d$-tuples $(a_1,..,a_d)$ with $a_i \in A_i$ and where multiplication and addition is componentwise. If you are to be "strict" this definition does not satisfy the correct universal property: The embedding $A_i \rightarrow A$ mapping $a$ to $(0,..,a,..,0)$ is not unital. The projection map $A \rightarrow A_i$ is a well defined map of unital commutative rings.

Comment: But this universal property is not the issue here: What you want is a constructive proof of existence of such a "decomposition" - this componentwise structure is clear from the proof of Thm 8.7 in AM.